# Best way to subset a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Hey I'm new to Pandas and I just came across `df.query()`.

Why people would use `df.query()` when you can directly filter your Dataframes using brackets notation ? The official pandas tutorial also seems to prefer the latter approach.

With brackets notation :

```
df[df['age'] <= 21]
```

With pandas query method :

```
df.query('age <= 21')
```

Besides some of the stylistic or flexibility differences that have been mentioned, is one canonically preferred - namely for performance of operations on large dataframes?

Comment: Because some people can not easily construct the correct filtering and aggregates, but know how to write something like SQL?

Comment: Because you might want to use a query obtained from a user or read from a file, or generated programmatically in some way.

Comment: When they were first released they had some performance benefits thanks to numexpr but I don't think they outperform boolean indexing now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the following sample DF:

```
In [307]: df
Out[307]:
  sex  age     name
0   M   40      Max
1   F   35     Anna
2   M   29      Joe
3   F   18    Maria
4   F   23  Natalie
```

There are quite a few good reasons to prefer `.query()` method.

- it might be much shorter and cleaner compared to boolean indexing:

  ```
  In [308]: df.query("20 <= age <= 30 and sex=='F'")
  Out[308]:
    sex  age     name
  4   F   23  Natalie

  In [309]: df[(df['age']>=20) & (df['age']<=30) & (df['sex']=='F')]
  Out[309]:
    sex  age     name
  4   F   23  Natalie
  ```
- you can prepare conditions (queries) programmatically:

  ```
  In [315]: conditions = {'name':'Joe', 'sex':'M'}

  In [316]: q = ' and '.join(['{}=="{}"'.format(k,v) for k,v in conditions.items()])

  In [317]: q
  Out[317]: 'name=="Joe" and sex=="M"'

  In [318]: df.query(q)
  Out[318]:
    sex  age name
  2   M   29  Joe
  ```

---

PS there are also some disadvantages:

- we can't use `.query()` method for columns containing spaces or columns that consist only from digits
- not all functions can be applied or in some cases we have to use `engine='python'` instead of default `engine='numexpr'` (which is faster)

NOTE: Jeff (one of the main Pandas contributors and a member of Pandas core team) [once said](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6508#issuecomment-283181667):

> Note that in reality .query is just a nice-to-have interface, in fact
>   it has very specific guarantees, meaning its meant to parse like a
>   query language, and not a fully general interface.

Comment: Maybe it is also worth noting [Jeff's comment](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6508#issuecomment-283181667) here: "Note that in reality .query is just a nice-to-have interface, in fact it has very specific guarantees, meaning its meant to parse like a query language, and not a fully general interface."

Comment: @ayhan, good point - thank you! I'll add it to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Some other interesting usages in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental).

#### [Reuseable](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#query-use-cases)

> A use case for query() is **when you have a collection of DataFrame
>   objects that have a subset of column names (or index levels/names) in
>   common.** You can pass the same query to both frames without having to
>   specify which frame you’re interested in querying -- [(Source)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#query-use-cases)

Example:

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], columns=["X", "Y", "Z"])
dfB = pd.DataFrame([[1,3,3], [4,1,6]], columns=["X", "Y", "Z"])
q = "(X > 3) & (Y < 10)"

print(dfA.query(q))
print(dfB.query(q))

   X  Y  Z
1  4  5  6
   X  Y  Z
1  4  1  6
```

#### [More flexible syntax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#query-python-versus-pandas-syntax-comparison)

```
df.query('a < b and b < c')  # understand a bit more English
```

#### [Support `in` operator and `not in` (alternative to `isin`)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-in-and-not-in-operators)

```
df.query('a in [3, 4, 5]') # select rows whose value of column a is in [2, 3, 4]
```

#### [Special usage of == and != (similar to `in`/`not in`)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#special-use-of-the-operator-with-list-objects)

```
df.query('a == [1, 3, 5]') # select whose value of column a is in [1, 3, 5]
# equivalent to df.query('a in [1, 3, 5]')
```