# How to use different combinations of group by while trying to get the top most viewed

Tags: python, pandas

Am trying to get the top most rating using groupby of multiple columns and if there is no combination of that particular groupby, its throwing me an error . how to do multiple combinations ?

data :

```
maritalstatus   gender age_range occ    rating
ma                 M    young   student  PG
ma                 F    adult   teacher  R
sin                M    young   student  PG
sin                M    adult   teacher  R
ma                 M    young   student  PG
sin                F    adult   teacher  R
```

code :

```
def get_top( maritalstatus, gender,age_range, occ):        
    m = df.groupby(['maritalstatus',' gender', 'age_range', 'occ'])
    ['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0 ])      
    mpaa = m[maritalstatus][gender][age_range][occ]    
    return mpaa
```

input :

```
get_top('ma', 'M', 'young','teacher)
```

output: 
    throws me an error as there is no such combination.

Here if there is no such combination my function should limit to, married, male and young and not teacher as there is no such combination.

Comment: Protip: Tag your pandas question with `pandas` if you want the right people to see it.

Comment: Thanks Aran for the tip.

Comment: Do you need solution which should be working with `get_top('ma', 'M', 'teacher)` or `get_top('M', 'young','teacher)` or `get_top('ma', 'teacher)` ?

Comment: first, it should look at a sequence, get_top('ma', 'm', 'young', 'teacher'), if its not there then get_top('ma', 'm', 'young') if this isnt there, then, get_top('ma', 'm')

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @pylang : input : get_top('ma', 'm', 'young', 'teacher') , using all the for args, it should work on all kinds of combinations and return outputs for the combinations which exist .

Comment: For clarity, you should post exactly the output you expect.  My post has an application for valid inputs.  You can wrap around that last function to memoize the last result and revert if a `KeyError` is observed.

Answer (score 0):

This is one non-pandas solution. `Counter.most_common()` orders results by most common descending counts.

```
from collections import Counter

def get_top(maritalstatus=None, gender=None, age_range=None, occ=None):

    cols = ['maritalstatus', 'gender', 'age_range', 'occ']
    values = [maritalstatus, gender, age_range, occ]

    c = Counter(df.query(' & '.join((('({0} ==  "{1}")').format(i, j)) \
                for i, j in zip(cols, values) if j))['rating'])

    return c.most_common()

get_top(maritalstatus='ma', gender='M', age_range='young')  # [('PG', 2)]
```

Comment: what if I dont have that combination? suppose, it  stopped at marital status, gender and age range ..it should only return me until there

Comment: @pylearner, see update. `q` is an arbitrary list of tuples, which can be fed in from a function.

Comment: can use that multiple columns ?

Comment: yea, so how do I list of columns to q ? say, a,b,c,d are my columns... in a sequence i can only use a,b,c as  a,b,c,d doesnt combine. ..so q should only have a,b,c ...how do i get it ?

Comment: see update, in the function just include the variables you are searching for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164879/discussion-between-pylearner-and-jp-data-analysis).

Comment: to be honest, i'd rather you define your input & expected output in the question. be explicit and give an example.

Comment: If you see my input in the question above, I have given some inputs of a new user, but in the data i havent had a teacher who is young ... so my function should only combine  'ma','m' and 'young'

Comment: @pylearner, yes. and i've given a solution where you can input between 1 & 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`*args`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/2901002) for dynamic input, (ordering of values cannot be changed)  with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filtering:

```
def get_top(*args):     
    c = ['maritalstatus', 'gender', 'age_range', 'occ']
    m = (df.groupby(c)['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
           .reset_index())
    args = list(args)
    while True:
        d = dict(zip(c, args))
        #https://stackoverflow.com/a/48371587/2901002
        q = ' & '.join((('({} ==  "{}")').format(i, j)) for i, j in d.items())
        m1 = m.query(q)['rating']  
        if m1.empty and len(args) > 1:
            args.pop()
        else:
            return m1

print(get_top('ma', 'M', 'young','teacher'))
1    PG
Name: rating, dtype: object
```

Comment: d = dict(zip(cols, args)),  I dont see cols anywhere, can you let me know where did you take it from ?

Comment: oops, it is `c`

Comment: Series([], Name: rating, dtype: object), thats my output.

Comment: With sample data?

Comment: Can you test `df = pd.DataFrame({'maritalstatus': ['ma', 'ma', 'sin', 'sin', 'ma', 'sin'], 'gender': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F'], 'age_range': ['young', 'adult', 'young', 'adult', 'young', 'adult'], 'occ': ['student', 'teacher', 'student', 'teacher', 'student', 'teacher'], 'rating': ['PG', 'R', 'PG', 'R', 'PG', 'R']})` ?

Comment: But if test `get_top('ma', 'M', 'young','teacher)` it return noting, because not such data in Dataframe.

Comment: yea, so if this _get_top('ma', 'M', 'young','teacher)_ is not returning anything, its should perform this _get_top('ma', 'm', 'young')_ ... automatically

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is definitely the goto library for handling detailed tabular data.  For those seeking a non-`pandas` option, you can build your own *mapping* and *reduction* functions.  I use these terms to mean the following:

- *mapping*: reorganize data grouped by a desired query
- *reduction*: an aggregation function, used to tally or condense many values to one

`pandas` analogous *groupby*/*aggregation* concepts.

**Given**

Cleaned data where multiple spaces have been replaced with a single delimiter, e.g. `","`.

```
%%file "test.txt"
status,gender,age_range,occ,rating
ma,M,young,student,PG
ma,F,adult,teacher,R
sin,M,young,student,PG
sin,M,adult,teacher,R
ma,M,young,student,PG
sin,F,adult,teacher,R
```

**Code**

```
import csv
import collections as ct
```

*Step 1: Read data*

```
def read_file(fname):
    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for line in reader:
            yield line


iterable = [line for line in read_file("test.txt")]
iterable
```

Output

```
[OrderedDict([('status', 'ma'),
              ('gender', 'M'),
              ('age_range', 'young'),
              ('occ', 'student'),
              ('rating', 'PG')]),
 OrderedDict([('status', 'ma'),
              ('gender', 'F'),
              ('age_range', 'adult'),
              ...]
 ...
]
```

*Step 2: Remap data*

```
def mapping(data, column):
    """Return a dict of regrouped data."""
    dd = ct.defaultdict(list)
    for d in data:
        key = d[column]
        value = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k != column}
        dd[key].append(value)
    return dict(dd)


mapping(iterable, "gender")
```

Output

```
{'M': [
   {'age_range': 'young', 'occ': 'student', 'rating': 'PG', ...},
   ...]
 'F': [
   {'status': 'ma', 'age_range': 'adult', ...},
   ...]
}
```

*Step 3: Reduce data*

```
def reduction(data):
    """Return a reduced mapping of Counters."""
    final = {}
    for key, val in data.items():
        agg = ct.defaultdict(ct.Counter)
        for d in val:
            for k, v in d.items():
                agg[k][v] += 1
        final[key] = dict(agg)
    return final

reduction(mapping(iterable, "gender"))
```

Output

```
{'F': {
   'age_range': Counter({'adult': 2}),
   'occ': Counter({'teacher': 2}),
   'rating': Counter({'R': 2}),
   'status': Counter({'ma': 1, 'sin': 1})},
 'M': {
   'age_range': Counter({'adult': 1, 'young': 3}),
   'occ': Counter({'student': 3, 'teacher': 1}),
   'rating': Counter({'PG': 3, 'R': 1}),
   'status': Counter({'ma': 2, 'sin': 2})}
 }
```

**Demo**

With these tools in place, you can build a data pipeline and to query the data, feeding results from one function into another:

```
# Find the top age range amoung males
pipeline = reduction(mapping(iterable, "gender"))
pipeline["M"]["age_range"].most_common(1)
# [('young', 3)]

# Find the top ratings among teachers
pipeline = reduction(mapping(iterable, "occ"))
pipeline["teacher"]["rating"].most_common()
# [('R', 3)]

# Find the number of married people
pipeline = reduction(mapping(iterable, "gender"))
sum(v["status"]["ma"] for k, v in pipeline.items())
# 3
```

Overall, you tailor your output based on how you define your reduction function.

Note, the code from this generalized process is more verbose than a [former example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680608/function-to-return-the-highest-count-value-using-a-rule) despite its powerful application to many data columns.  `pandas` succinctly encapsulates these concepts.  Although the learning curve may initially be more steep, it can greatly expedite data analysis.

---

**Details**

1. *Read data* - we parse each line of a *cleaned file* using [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), which maintains the header names as keys of a dictionary.  This structure facilitates easier column access by name.
2. *Remap data* - we group data as a dictionary.

   - The keys are items in the selected/queried column, e.g. `"M"`, `"F"`.
   - The values are each a list of dictionaries.  Each dictionary represents a row of all remaining columnar data (excluding the key).
3. *Reduce data* - we aggregate the values of the remapped data by tabulating related entries for all listed dictionaries.  Together the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) combination build an excellent reducing data structure where new entries to the `defaultdict` initialize a `Counter` and repeated entries simply tally observations.

**Application**

Pipelines are optional.  Here we will build a single function that processes serial requests:

```
def serial_reduction(iterable, val_queries):
    """Return a `Counter` that is reduced after serial queries."""
    q1, *qs = val_queries 
    val_to_key = {v:k for k, v in iterable[0].items()}
    values_list = mapping(iterable, val_to_key[q1])[q1]

    counter = ct.Counter()
    # Process queries for dicts in each row and build a counter
    for q in qs:    
        try:
            for row in values_list[:]:
                if val_to_key[q] not in row:
                    continue
                else:
                    reduced_vals = {v for v in row.values() if v not in qs}
            for val in reduced_vals:
                counter[val] += 1
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("'{}' not found. Try a new query.".format(q))
    return counter


c = serial_reduction(iterable, "ma M young".split())
c.most_common()
# [('student', 2), ('PG', 2)]
serial_reduction(iterable, "ma M young teacher".split())
# ValueError: 'teacher' not found. Try a new query.
```